# best way to get QueryStrings or which one is faster?

Tags: asp.net

There are several way to get QueryStrings in ASP.NET

which one of them is beter and faster ?

I want to get 4 QueryString from my url, is it good to use

```
Request.QueryString["name"];
```

OR

```
    HttpRequest q = Request;
    NameValueCollection n = q.QueryString;
```

?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a simplicity perspective, since you know what you want to find it seems the first option is the most straight-forward.  Instantiating another object, against which you'll then have to find your query string values, seems duplicative.  The performance difference should be trivial.